# What is the probability that at least one of the pot has a hidden bug?

Tags: probability

There are $10$ pots exposed in the shop, $2$ of which have hidden defects. The customer buys $2$ pieces. What is the probability that at least one of them has a hidden bug ?

Does the probability of at least one pot has a hidden bug equal to $1$-$P(\text{all of them are perfect})$?

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it does not adhere to the spirit of Mathematics Stack Exchange: what have you tried? Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: Your plan of attack is good.  If you can compute the probability that both of selected pots are perfect you get your answer by subtracting from $1$.

Comment: So the probability of the customer selecting two perfect pots are $f\frac{28}{45}$. The probability of he/she selecting at least one defective pot will be $1-\frac{28}{45}=\frac{17}{45}$

Comment: Looks good! $\quad$.

Comment: As a software engineer, I'm familiar with the practice of calling defects "bugs," but when you say there is a hidden bug in a pot it sounds to me like someone has deliberately placed a microphone in the pot in order to spy on the purchaser. For some reason I found this amusing.